# Rewriting url with the following regular expression

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a mod rewrite to get this url: localhost/test/index.php?hello

I created a file for this page called hello.php and it is in the folder /test

To clarify, I have another page that has a link to my hello.php, but what is the correct url so I can display localhost/test/index.php?hello in the url when I click the link to access my hello.php page.

The following doesn't seem like it is right:

```
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: please clarify for me, do you want hello.php to be shown on `index.php?hello` url?

Comment: yes, I want hello.php to show as index.php?hello when I click a link to that page

Comment: You want to show `hello.php` in address bar but be sent to `index.php?hello`? If you're trying to make friendly URL's did you check my answer?

Comment: I tried yours.   
 
How do I test? Do I just type in localhost/test/index.php?hello. I'm confusing myself now. It doesn't seem like it is working. I type in localhost/test/index.php/?hello. It doesn't bring me to the hello.php page.

Comment: That's not what it does. I assumed you wanted "friendly URLS" like most people. What my answer does is allow you to type in `localhost/test/hello.php` and it will internally redirect to `index.php?hello` and your users will always see `localhost/test/hello.php` Also when replying you need to put our username like @pjack or we won't get notified you left a reply. I just happened to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to just do php files.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

To clarify what my answer does. It gives you more friendly URLs which it sounded like what your were asking for.

So you can use `localhost/hello.php` and it will be `internally` redirect to `/localhost/index.php?hello`. Internally means they will never see `localhost/index.php?hello` and will always see `localhost/hello.php` in their browser.

You can do any URL and it will rewrite to a php file. e.g. `localhost/index.php?newpage` and you can use `/localhost/newpage.php`

Hope that is clearer.

**EDIT**

You want the reverse but I don't know how your PHP is constructed but query strings are typically field/value pairs. For example `name=john`, `page=contact`, `action=hello` etc. You have `index.php?hello` but `hello` has no content or value.

That's probably why you're having such a hard time even re-writing your URL. Using `$_GET`would require a value.

So what **I would** do, is if your URL was like this using field/value pairs

```
index.php?action=hello
```

Then in the index.php file you could do something like

```
$action = $_GET["action"];

if($action == "hello"){
//show contents of hello, include a page or whatever
}
```

Once you have good URLs it would be easy to rewrite it.

So if the URL that you want shown is like

`index.php?action=hello` and you want to redirect it to `hello.php`

Your .htaccess would look like this

```
RewriteRule ^action=([^/]+) /$1.php [R,L]
```

That would redirect it to the php file. If you don't want to show the redirection and keep it an internal redirect you can remove the `R` flag and just keep `[L]`.

I personally **don't** want the user to see really long query strings URL example. `mysite.com?page=music&artist=someartist&title=sometitle`

So all my URL's are rewritten to be shorter and friendlier like my original answer.

Comment: Ohh I see. Is there a reverse order? I want to see localhost/index.php?hello instead of localhost/hello.php

Comment: Would it be this way? 
<pre><code>RewriteRule  (.*)\/index.php?$1 (.*)\.php$ [L]</code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need .htaccess for 2. as far as you're using GET parametr - use it in index.php:

   ```
   if (isset($_GET['hello'])) include('hello.php');
   ```

this will show the contents of hello.php inside index.php